# MUI, ReactSuite: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, suite

I'm using Modal component from React Suite and Select component from MUI

Basically I have an open button that opens a modal popup which has inside, a select component

However, when I open console, it produces the following error when I open the modal and select something from the Select menu:

```
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at Object.current (Modal.js:131:1)
    at useEventCallback.js:19:1
    at Object.current (Modal.js:139:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (useEventCallback.js:19:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at Object.current (Modal.js:131:1)
    at useEventCallback.js:19:1
    at Object.current (Modal.js:139:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (useEventCallback.js:19:1)
```

I have not edited anything except just copying and pasting the sample code from both the Modal and Select components(pasting it inside the <Modal.Body>) from React Suite and MUI respectively, any idea what's causing the error?

Thanks in advance

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Modal, Toggle, ButtonToolbar } from "rsuite";

import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

const names = [
  "Oliver Hansen",
  "Van Henry",
  "April Tucker",
  "Ralph Hubbard",
  "Omar Alexander",
  "Carlos Abbott",
  "Miriam Wagner",
  "Bradley Wilkerson",
  "Virginia Andrews",
  "Kelly Snyder",
];

function Box() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setPersonName(
      // On autofill we get a stringified value.
      typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="modal-container">
      <ButtonToolbar>
        <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open</Button>
      </ButtonToolbar>

      <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Title>Modal Title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div>
            <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
              <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Tag</InputLabel>
              <Select
                labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
                id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
                multiple
                value={personName}
                onChange={handleChange}
                input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
                renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
                MenuProps={MenuProps}
              >
                {names.map((name) => (
                  <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
                    <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
                    <ListItemText primary={name} />
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} appearance="primary">
            Ok
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} appearance="subtle">
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Box;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not better way to solve this, but set this attribute **disableEnforceFocus** in your Modal tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).